# convert pdf to html page wise using pdfbox library

Tags: java, pdfbox

public class ExtractText
{

```
/**
 * private constructor.
*/
private ExtractText()
{
    //static class
}


public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{


     if(l!=null)
     {
         System.out.println("HERE"+l.length);
         deleteSubs(op);
         System.out.println("Then"+l.length);
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("WHERE");
     }

    File y=new File(imgDes);

    if(!y.exists())
    {
        y.mkdirs();
    }
   File z=new File(imgDestination);

   if(!z.exists())
   {
       z.mkdirs();
   }
  File fr=new File(outputFile);

  if(!fr.isDirectory())
  {
      fr.delete();
  }
    // Defaults to text files
    String ext = ".txt";
    int startPage = 1;
    int endPage = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
     Writer output = null;
     PDDocument document =null;       
    try
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL( pdfFile );

            document = PDDocument.load(url, force);

            String fileName = url.getFile();
            if( outputFile == null && fileName.length() >4)
            {
                outputFile = new File( fileName.substring( 0, fileName.length() -4 ) + ext ).getName();
            }
        }
        catch( MalformedURLException e)
        {
            document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile, force);

            if( outputFile == null && pdfFile.length() >4 )
            {
                outputFile = pdfFile.substring( 0, pdfFile.length() -4 ) + ext;
            }
        }

            //document.print();
        if( document.isEncrypted() )
        {
            StandardDecryptionMaterial sdm = new StandardDecryptionMaterial( password );
            document.openProtection(sdm);
            AccessPermission ap = document.getCurrentAccessPermission();
            if( ! ap.canExtractContent() )
            {
                throw new IOException("You do not have permission to extract text" );
            }
        }

        if ((encoding == null) && (toHTML))
        {
            encoding = "UTF-8";
        }
        if( toConsole )
        {
            output = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);                                                  
        }
        else
        {
          if( encoding != null )
           {
                output = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream( outputFile ), encoding );
           }
         else
            {
                    //use default encoding
                output = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream( outputFile ) );
            }
        }

        PDFTextStripper4 stripper = null;

        if(toHTML)
        {
            stripper = new PDFText2HTML(encoding);
        }

        else
        {
            stripper = new PDFTextStripper4(encoding);
        }
        File f= new File(imgDestination);
        PDDocument pd;

        int i=0;
        if(f.exists())
        {
            pd=PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
            PDFontDescriptor fd;
            fd = new PDFontDescriptorDictionary();

            List<PDPage> li=pd.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
            for(PDPage page:li)
            {
              PDResources pdr=page.getResources();

              Map<String, PDFont> m=pdr.getFonts();
              PDStream pst;
            for(PDFont pdd:m.values())
            {
                   System.out.println("----------"+pdd.getBaseFont());
                   pdd.getFontDescriptor();
                    fd = pdd.getFontDescriptor();

                   pdd.setFontDescriptor((PDFontDescriptorDictionary)fd);
                   System.out.println("tititititi"+pdd.getFontEncoding());
                   if(pdd.isType1Font())
                   {
                    pst=((PDFontDescriptorDictionary) fd).getFontFile3();
                    System.out.println("In If "+pst);
                   if(pst!= null)
                   {
                       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(imgDestination+pdd.getBaseFont().toString()+".pfb"));
                       IOUtils.copy(pst.createInputStream(), fos);
                       i++;
                       System.out.println(i);
                       fos.close();
                    }
                   }
                   else 
                       if(pdd.isTrueTypeFont())
                       {
                           pst= ((PDFontDescriptorDictionary) fd).getFontFile2();
                           System.out.println("In Else-if"+pst);
                           if (pst!= null)
                           {
                               FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(imgDestination+pdd.getBaseFont().toString()+".ttf"));
                               IOUtils.copy(pst.createInputStream(), fos);
                               i++;
                               System.out.println(i);
                               fos.close();
                           }
                       }
                       else
                           if(pdd.isSymbolicFont())
                           {
                               System.out.println("Symbol.......");
                           }
                   else
                   {

                       System.out.println("In Else");



                   }
               }

            }

        int pageCount = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().size();
        for (int p = 0; p < pageCount; ++p)
        {
            System.out.println("I am in for loop");
             stripper.setForceParsing( force );
             stripper.setSortByPosition( true );
             stripper.setShouldSeparateByBeads(separateBeads);
            stripper.setStartPage( p);
            stripper.setEndPage( p);
            stripper.writeText( document, output );
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(f5+(p+1)+".html"));
            output.close();


        }

        PDDocumentInformation info = document.getDocumentInformation();
        System.out.println( "Page Count=" + document.getNumberOfPages());
        System.out.println( "Title=" + info.getTitle());
        System.out.println( "Author=" + info.getAuthor());
        System.out.println( "Subject=" + info.getSubject() );
        System.out.println( "Keywords=" + info.getKeywords() );
        System.out.println( "Creator=" + info.getCreator() );
        System.out.println( "Producer=" + info.getProducer() );
        System.out.println( "Creation Date=" + info.getCreationDate() );
        System.out.println( "Modification Date=" + info.getModificationDate());
        System.out.println( "Trapped=" + info.getTrapped());


   }
    }catch(Exception e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
    finally
    {
        if( output != null)
        {
            output.close();
        }
        if( document != null )
        {
            document.close();
        }
    }
}


private static void deleteSubs(File op) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     File[] files = op.listFiles();
     System.out.print("In delete folder");
        if(files!=null) 
        {
            //some JVMs return null for empty dirs
            for(File f: files) 
            {
                if(f.isDirectory()) 
                {
                    deleteSubs(f);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    f.delete();
                }
            }
        }
        op.delete();
}
```

}

now i am able to get entire pdf to a  html file i.e.. I am extracting text only not images but i want to get every page of a pdf in to single html  so any solution for this is quite helpful to me.. ThankYou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your question: just set

```
    stripper.setStartPage( p );
    stripper.setEndPage( p );
```

accordingly. So you would loop somewhat like this:

```
int pageCount = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().size();
for (int p = 0; p < pageCount; ++p)
{
    //... your options
    stripper.setStartPage(p);
    stripper.setEndPage(p);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(f5+(p+1)+".html"));
    stripper.writeText(document, fos);
    fos.close();
}
```

Btw if you get an exception relating to the sorting comparator, use setSortByPosition(false), or wait for version 1.8.8 where this problem is fixed.

Comment: sir first splitting my pdf and then converting each page in to .html is this a possible way?

Comment: sure, if you like it the hard & slow way :-) download the command line application, and use the PDFSplit command. https://pdfbox.apache.org/commandline/#pdfSplit  But the solution I presented will be faster.

Comment: for (int p = 0; p < pageCount; ++p)
            {
             System.out.println("I am in for loop");
              stripper.setForceParsing( force );
                 stripper.setSortByPosition( true );
                 stripper.setShouldSeparateByBeads(separateBeads);
                stripper.setStartPage( p);
                stripper.setEndPage( p);
                stripper.writeText( document, output );
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(f5+p+".html"));

                
            } siris this the correct way i am doing? here f5 is path

Comment: yes, something like that. Maybe use new File(f5+"-"+(p+1)+".html") if your client doesn't like zerobased page numbers :-)

Comment: sir but i'm getting empty html files

Comment: Maybe close output after calling writeText. If it still doesn't work - did it work before, i.e. when you had all on one HTML file? Some files don't support text extraction. Try copy & paste from Adobe Reader.

Comment: The code you show writes html to "output", not to "fos", i.e. you were writing to the "all pages" html file.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You need to make sure that you're writing to the correct stream, i.e. to the one you're opening every time ("fos"), not to the old one ("output")!!