# convert pdf to html pagewise using pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am converting pdf to html by overriding processTextPosition method in PDFTextStripper
know I am getting entire text in to a single .html but I want every pdfpage as .html is there any way to do it through processTextPosition method my code is:
here "f" is path 
processTextPosition is called from its sub class PDFText2Html

```
protected void processTextPosition( TextPosition text )
{  
    boolean showCharacter = true;
    PositionWrapper p =new PositionWrapper(text);
    TextPosition t=p.getTextPosition();


    try
    {




            f.createNewFile();
            bw= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, true) );


                float a;
                a = t.getTextPos().getYPosition();
                b=compare(a,b,t);
                System.out.println(b);


} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    try 
        {
         bw.flush();
         bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) 
         {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
 }


    if(suppressDuplicateOverlappingText)
    {
        showCharacter = false;
        String textCharacter = text.getCharacter();
        float textX = text.getX();
        float textY = text.getY();
        TreeMap<Float, TreeSet<Float>> sameTextCharacters = characterListMapping.get( textCharacter );
        if(sameTextCharacters == null )
        {
            sameTextCharacters = new TreeMap<Float, TreeSet<Float>>();
            characterListMapping.put( textCharacter, sameTextCharacters );
        }

        boolean suppressCharacter = false;
        float tolerance = (text.getWidth()/textCharacter.length())/3.0f;
        SortedMap<Float, TreeSet<Float>> xMatches =
            sameTextCharacters.subMap(textX - tolerance, textX + tolerance);
        for(TreeSet<Float> xMatch : xMatches.values()) 
        {
            SortedSet<Float> yMatches =
                xMatch.subSet(textY - tolerance , textY + tolerance);
            if (!yMatches.isEmpty()) 
            {
                suppressCharacter = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if( !suppressCharacter )
        {
            TreeSet<Float> ySet = sameTextCharacters.get(textX);
            if (ySet == null) 
            {
                ySet = new TreeSet<Float>();
                sameTextCharacters.put( textX,  ySet );
            }
            ySet.add( textY );
            showCharacter = true;
        }
    }
    if( showCharacter )
    {

        int foundArticleDivisionIndex = -1;
        int notFoundButFirstLeftAndAboveArticleDivisionIndex = -1;
        int notFoundButFirstLeftArticleDivisionIndex = -1;
        int notFoundButFirstAboveArticleDivisionIndex = -1;
        float x = text.getX();
        float y = text.getY();
        if( shouldSeparateByBeads )
        {
            for( int i=0; i<pageArticles.size() && foundArticleDivisionIndex == -1; i++ )
            {
                PDThreadBead bead = (PDThreadBead)pageArticles.get( i );
                if( bead != null )
                {
                    PDRectangle rect = bead.getRectangle();
                    if(rect.contains( x, y ) )
                    {
                        foundArticleDivisionIndex = i*2+1;
                    }
                    else if( (x < rect.getLowerLeftX() ||
                            y < rect.getUpperRightY()) &&
                            notFoundButFirstLeftAndAboveArticleDivisionIndex == -1)
                    {
                        notFoundButFirstLeftAndAboveArticleDivisionIndex = i*2;
                    }
                    else if( x < rect.getLowerLeftX() &&
                            notFoundButFirstLeftArticleDivisionIndex == -1)
                    {
                        notFoundButFirstLeftArticleDivisionIndex = i*2;
                    }
                    else if( y < rect.getUpperRightY() &&
                            notFoundButFirstAboveArticleDivisionIndex == -1)
                    {
                        notFoundButFirstAboveArticleDivisionIndex = i*2;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foundArticleDivisionIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foundArticleDivisionIndex = 0;
        }
        int articleDivisionIndex = -1;
        if( foundArticleDivisionIndex != -1 )
        {
            articleDivisionIndex = foundArticleDivisionIndex;
        }
        else if( notFoundButFirstLeftAndAboveArticleDivisionIndex != -1 )
        {
            articleDivisionIndex = notFoundButFirstLeftAndAboveArticleDivisionIndex;
        }
        else if( notFoundButFirstLeftArticleDivisionIndex != -1 )
        {
            articleDivisionIndex = notFoundButFirstLeftArticleDivisionIndex;
        }
        else if( notFoundButFirstAboveArticleDivisionIndex != -1 )
        {
            articleDivisionIndex = notFoundButFirstAboveArticleDivisionIndex;
        }
        else
        {
            articleDivisionIndex = charactersByArticle.size()-1;
        }

        List<TextPosition> textList = (List<TextPosition>) charactersByArticle.get( articleDivisionIndex );


        if(textList.isEmpty())
        {
            textList.add(text);
        }
        else
        {
            TextPosition previousTextPosition = (TextPosition)textList.get(textList.size()-1);
            if(text.isDiacritic() && previousTextPosition.contains(text))
            {
                previousTextPosition.mergeDiacritic(text, normalize);
            }
            /* If the previous TextPosition was the diacritic, merge it into this
             * one and remove it from the list. */
            else if(previousTextPosition.isDiacritic() && text.contains(previousTextPosition))
            {
                text.mergeDiacritic(previousTextPosition, normalize);
                textList.remove(textList.size()-1);
                textList.add(text);
            }
            else
            {
                textList.add(text);
            }
        }
    }

   }
```

and my compare method body is

```
private float compare(float a, float b, TextPosition t) throws IOException 
{ 
if(a==b)
{

    bw.write("<span style=\"font-size:"+t.getFontSizeInPt()+"pt;"+ "fontfamily:"+t.getFont().getBaseFont()+ "width:"+t.getWidth()+"left:"+t.getTextPos().getXPosition()+"pt;top:"+t.getTextPos().getYPosition()+";\">"+t.getCharacter()+"</span>");
    b=a;
}
else
{
    b=a;

    bw.write("<br>"+"<span style=\"font-size:"+t.getFontSizeInPt()+"pt;"+ "fontfamily:"+t.getFont().getBaseFont()+ "width:"+t.getWidth()+"left:"+t.getTextPos().getXPosition()+"pt;top:"+t.getTextPos().getYPosition()+";\">"+t.getCharacter()+"</span>");
}
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268879/convert-pdf-to-html-page-wise-using-pdfbox-library/27270748#27270748) help you, and if not, why not?

Comment: no because if I proceed with that I am not able to get position and other properties of each and every character in .html but if I go in this way i get all properties of every character

Comment: this is very confusing. "b" has no declaration, and neither has "bw". Anyway, why not using the output element that you get when doing the call to writeText() as in the link? You extended PDFTextStripper so you can use its variables, e.g. "output".

Comment: I didn't declared them locally  BufferedWriter bw=null;float b; and I can't use that output element because I want to get properties of every character in the pdf ?

Comment: Then just set a new name when you call writeText() for one page, i.e. put an extra parameter in writeText() that sets a page-dependent name for "f".

Comment: sir I am not able to understand what you are saying can u place some sample code

Comment: public void writeText( PDDocument doc, Writer outputStream, String filename ) throws IOException
{
  this.f = filename;
  super.writeText (doc, outputStream);
}
this way "f" can be different for each page, if you call writeText once per page as in the link I mentioned earlier. However I also doubt that I have really understood what you are attempting to do.

Comment: yes exactly I think that you didn't understand but I need your help

Comment: what I want is when i go with writeText() text is extracted ok but what  I need is each and every single character font size its xposition, yposition... I thought that it is only possible through processTextPosition() and suceeded in doing so but what I need is that o/p which i am writing to single .html file is to be write to seperate files i.e.. every pdf page to .html

Comment: maybe improve the question, so that it contains not only your extended PDFTextStripper class, but also all the cally to it.

Comment: placed my entire processTextPosition()

Comment: The call to your extended PDFTextStripper class is still missing. And did you (as I assumed) extend PDFTextStripper, or did you make changes directly in the PDFBox source code and then call PDFText2Html?

Comment: yes right I directly made changes

Comment: Ok, got that. Now please add the call to PDFText2Html, which is likely a loop.

Comment: where I had to add that one

Comment: into the question. My understanding is that you are calling PDFText2Html, which itself extends your (modified) PDFTextStripper.

Comment: PDFText2Html added sir

Comment: No, I meant to call to PDFText2Html. Somehow, somewhere you're calling PDFText2Html, i.e. there is a "new PDFText2Html" call.

Comment: ya that PDFText2Html() constructor I am calling from another class ExtractText which is the main class

Comment: You didn't add the call to PDFText2Html :-( I give up :-( I still think that my very first remark (with the link) is the solution, i.e. pass different files for each page when calling PDFText2Html.writeText for each page separately. Whats next? a) wait for another person to answer, the user mkl is very good, b) ask the question again in the PDFBox user mailing list so other users might answer including three other PDFBox committers, but don't just copy & paste the question, make a new (better) question based on my feedback.